# Is there a way of checking if a user defined class is initialized or not?

Tags: c++

Consider the class below

```
    class test;
    class sample
    {
        sample() { }
        ~sample(){}
        void SomeMethod();
        private: 
        test t;
    };

sample::SomeMethod(test &t1)
{

  if(t.isuninitialized())
  {
    t = t1;
  }
  else
  {
    // Check if t and t1 member values are the same
  } 
}

main()
{
  sample s;
  test t1(a); 
  s.someMethod(t1);
}
```

Is there a way to check if object t is initialized or not? In case of pointers it would suffice to check if the object is NULL. However, in this case, where t is not a pointer can such a check be done, or do I need to write a method that checks if the member variable values are initialized to default value

Comment: Define what "initialized" means to you in this context.

Comment: Why do you need to check for this? Whenever someone instantiates a `sample` object, and the `sample` and `test` constructors do not throw exceptions, then `t` will be initialized. What exactly is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Are you trying to insure some initialization function is always called before something else is used?

Comment: initialized? constructor is always called. what's "initialized" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact the compiler can check this for you: if the code compiles, the compiler was able to generate code which calls the default constructor of `test`, which in turn takes care of creating the object - so the object exists, and is initialized to some (possibly unknown, depending on how the `test` default constructor is implemented) state.